# How to redirect to a page from a non controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a non controller file called MyLib.cs in this I have a method that on given condition I want it to redirect to a page.

I used: "RedirectToAction()" but I got an error saying it dose not exist in current context.

Any ideas what I should use?

Thanks!

Comment: Post some code and explain your problem with more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use Response.Redirect here.
Consider this code

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("YOUR_PAGE_Virtual_PATH"); 
    // example: http://www.mywebsite.com/home/list
```

Give it a try and let us know if it worked.

*P.S: don't forget to mark as answer if this answer really helped you, thanks.*

Comment: Bit late, but since it helped me. I don't know if they've changed it or because I'm using asp.net core but I had to use HttpContext.Response.Redirect("path"); (without the 'Current').

Answer (score 1):

This is against some of the MVC tenets, you're breaking the Separation of Concerns concept, only the controllers should return views, not your libs.
I can give you two suggestions:

1. In your lib return a Enum, and
   them the controller would figure out
   which view should be displayed.
2. If not all paths from your lib
   causes a redirection, throw an exception and the controller handles it redirecting to the appropriate view.

Answer (score 0):

I assume MyLib is called from within a controller?

Could you set variable in MyLib.cs and redirect from your controller based on that once MyLib has finished?

**Update :**

Do you absolutely ***have*** to redirect from this class? I say this because this is going against the MVC paradigm. You should really be handling all your routing within your controllers. Sticking to it really will make your application far more maintainable. Really can't stress that enough! :)